# Base conversion error in matlab code

Tags: math, matlab

I created the following simple matlab functions to convert a number from an arbitrary base to decimal and back

this is the first one

```
function decNum = base2decimal(vec, base)

decNum = vec(1);
for d = 1:1:length(vec)-1
    decNum = decNum*base + vec(d+1);     
end
```

and here is the other one

```
function baseNum = decimal2base(num, base, Vlen)
ii = 1;
if num == 0
    baseNum = 0;
end
while num ~= 0 
    baseNum(ii) = mod(num, base);
    num = floor(num./base);
    ii = ii+1;
end
baseNum = fliplr(baseNum);

if Vlen>(length(baseNum))
    baseNum = [zeros(1,(Vlen)-(length(baseNum))) baseNum ];
end
```

Due to the fact that there are limitations to how big a number can be these functions can't successfully convert vary big vectors, but while testing them I noticed the following bug

Let's use the following testing function

```
num = 201;

pCount = 7
x=base2decimal(repmat(num-1, 1, pCount), num)
repmat(num-1, 1, pCount)
y=decimal2base(x, num, 1)
isequal(repmat(num-1, 1, pCount),y)
```

A supposed vector with **seven (7)** digits in **base201** works fine, but the same vector with **base200** does not return the expected result even though it is smaller and theoretically should be converted successfully.

Comment: You have two functions that some how don't work in combination. All in all this is quite a bit of code. Please try to test them individually to find the source of the problem and zoom in on the problem area in the code. Once you trim it down to 3 lines or so, we can easily help you and probably you can already solve the problem yourself.

Comment: You could try to go over to cells. seems to be easier. An alternative is to have a maximal permitted number and then fill up with zeros. There is a reason that this is how things usually is done.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin it is a bit hard debugging this sort of code that way as it deals with very big numbers and as I stated it works fine except for some 'weird' cases as the one I mentioned, so I was mostly hoping someone else had encountered this behavior, as my conversion functions are directly taken from what we know from theory about number bases (unless I have done some obvious mistake).

Comment: @patrik I am not sure i understood your suggestion correctly, the number [200] should be within bounds as the one bigger than it [201] seems to be ok.

Comment: with base `200` and the vector `[199,199,199,199,199,199,199]` the  `base2decimal` function on the last step of the loop calculates 63999999999999.0*200+199 which I assume due to floating point limitations equals 12800000000000000.0 instead of 12799999999999999.0, but this is not expected to be a floating point error as `eps(12799999999999999.0) = 0.5` so it seems this it can hold this accuracy... although as `eps(1.28e16)=2`  the calculated number is the last integer-valued double with accuracy less than 1.

Comment: What is the parameter `vec` of the function `base2decimal`? Is it an array of digits (as numeric) in base `base`, or is an array of `char` (i.e. a string)? If is  an array of numeric digits, first element is the most significant, or the least significant?

Comment: @CST-Link The values from `vec` are added to eachother, that should rule out a string.

Comment: What I mean is that when you deal with bases larger than 10 you need to split it up to chucks of your base. Eg, base 100 must be split up into a vector `[xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,...]` depending on the length of the number. Where each element can take values from 0-99. If you have numbers of different value eg. 2 numbers with value 42342442 and 34, you need to fill up the unused elements with 00 or store each number as a cell. 100 is a stupid base though since it can be obtained by splitting a decimal in chuck of 2. For another base, eg 105, the vector looks like `v=[xxx,xxx,...]` where `max(v)` is 104

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Thanks for your comment, Dennis. I'm trying to see what was the code writer's intent behind the code, to match it with the real implementation, so, from this point of view, my question makes sense. On the other hand, you may add in MATLAB `'a'*16 + 'b'` and make it look like is the value of `ab` in hex, though it's really not :-).

Comment: @patrik no that is not related to my question, even though you are correct one obviously should use a vector to represent numbers in very big bases.

Comment: Sorry I just saw that this is what you did. By the way do you mean the same example or the vector `[200,200,...]` did not work with the base 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(One preliminary comment: calling `base2decimal` won't result in a decimal number but rather in a number :-D)

This is due floating-point limited precision (in our case, `double`). To test it, just type at the MATLAB Command Window:

```
>> 200^7 - 1 == 200^7

ans = 

     1

>> mod(200^7 - 1, 200)

ans =

     0
```

which means that the value of your number in base 200 (which is precisely 200<sup>7</sup>−1) is represented exactly as 200<sup>7</sup>, and the "true" value of representation is  200<sup>7</sup>.

On the other hand:

```
>> 201^7 - 1 == 201^7

ans =

 1
```

so still the two numbers are represented the same, but

```
>> mod(201^7 - 1, 201)

ans =

   200
```

which means that the two values share the "true" representation of 201<sup>7</sup>−1, which, by accident, is the value that you expected.

**TL;DR**

When stored in a `double`, 200<sup>7</sup>−1 is inaccurately represented as 200<sup>7</sup>, while 201<sup>7</sup>−1 is accurately represented.

"Bigger numbers are less accurately represented than smaller numbers" is a misconception: if it was true, there would be no big numbers that could be *exactly* represented.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your own observations:

1. The code works fine in most cases
2. The code can give small errors for large numbers

The suspect is apparent:

Rounding issues seem to give you headaces here. This is also illustrated by @RTL in the comments.

---

The first question should now be:
1. Do you need perfect accuracy for such large numbers? Or is it ok if it is off by a relatively small amount sometimes?

If that is answered with a yes, I would recommend you to try a different storage format.
The simple solution would be to use big integers:

```
uint64
```

The alternative would be to make your own storage format. This is required if you need even bigger numbers. I think you can cover a huge range with a cell array and some tricks, but of course it is going to be hard to combine those numbers afterwards without losing the accuracy that you worked so hard for.

Comment: I do not like it. You need to let every "number" have the same number of digits like `v=[xxx,xxx,xxx,...]`, eg a number 211 for base 105 should be a vector `v=[002,001]`. This also allows decimals.

Comment: @patrik Not sure about the comment, but I also found a pair of functions: `bigbase2dec` and `dec2bigbase`. These are likely bugfree but of course they will still have limitations. See near the bottom of [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/6810).

Comment: This is certainly nice, but what I mean is that the same as each decimal digit is **one** element of the number, the base larger than decimals still need to consist of **one** element. Since matlab still uses base 10 you will need to come up with something else. Eg a vector of elements. For example 215 in base 100 is `[02,15]`.